# Celery worker receiving task even I have no message on RabbitMQ queue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

**Scenario:**

I had created a shared_task on celery for testing purpose [RabbitMQ as a Broker for queuing messages]:

```
@app.task(bind=True, max_retries = 5, base=MyTask)
def testing(self):
    try:
        raise smtplib.SMTPException

    except smtplib.SMTPException as exc:
        print 'This is it'
        self.retry(exc=exc, countdown=2)


#Overriding base class of Task
class MyTask(celery.Task):
    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        print "MyTask on failure world"
        pass
```

I called the task for testing by entering command **testing.delay()** by 10 times after creating a worker. And I just quit the server by pressing Ctrl+C and delete all those queues from RabbitMQ server. And again I started the server.

**Server starting command:** `celery worker --app=my_app.settings -l DEBUG`

**Delete command of queue:** `rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=<queue_name>`

**Deleting workers command:** `ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

**Problem:**

Since I have already deleted all queues from the RabbitMQ server, now only fresh tasks should be received. But I am still getting old tasks, moreover, no new tasks are appearing on the list. What would be the actual cause of this?

Answer (score 3):

What is happening is your worker takes in more than one task, unless you have the `-Ofair` flag when starting the worker

https://medium.com/@taylorhughes/three-quick-tips-from-two-years-with-celery-c05ff9d7f9eb

So, even if you clear out your queue, your worker will still be running with the tasks its already picked up, unless you kill the worker process itself.

Edit to add

If you have a task running after restart, you need to revoke the task.

http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-cancel-the-execution-of-a-task

Comment: Even after killing celery workers from command by typing: `ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9` and also after re-starting my computer, I am receiving those tasks. From where I am getting those messages?

Comment: because you haven't revoked the task.  http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-cancel-the-execution-of-a-task

Comment: Those above tasks were executed without that revoke method call. Now, how can I clear those tasks list? Can I see task_id of those remaining task?

Comment: use celery worker inspection, specifically active http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#inspecting-workers